# Open modal upon submit button after validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open a Modal upon clicking submit button if the user input some value,otherwise there is no need to open the modal.

presently, when clicking sumbit button the modal is opening without validating the *required* feild

**Here's the form**

```
<form action=" " method="POST">
    <label> Employee ID &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" required><br><br><br>
    <input type="submit"  onclick="mdl1()" value="Update">
    <button type="submit"  onclick="mdl2()" style="margin-left:100px;"> Delete</button><br>
</form>
```

**Modal for Update**

```
<div id="Modal_update" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="close_mdl1()">&times;</span>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="home.php" method="POST">
        <label><b>Employee ID</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter User ID" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID'] ?>" required>
        <label><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Name'] ?>" required>
        <label><b>Employee Type</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Temporary/Permanent" name="emp_type" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Emp_type'] ?>" required>
        <button type="submit" class="modalbutton" name="update">Update</button><br>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code for mdl1()**

```
function mdl1() {
  document.getElementById('Modal_update').style.display = "block";
}

function close_mdl1() {
  document.getElementById('Modal_update').style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('Modal_update')) {
    document.getElementById('Modal_update').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Please change the button type "Submit" to "Button". Then Check it.

Comment: I don't see where you've given any of your inputs an id. <input id="something" name="something>

getElementById requires an id for that element.

Comment: @Difster I've given id to the Div instead of inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
function mdl1() {
  var id = document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
  if(id != ''){
    document.getElementById('Modal_update').style.display = "block";
  }else{
    alert('Employee ID can not be empty.');
  }
}
```

Note: Make sure you don't have same name.

Comment: but how can i use some php validation to this input?

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];

if($id == ''){
 echo 'Employee ID can not be empty.';
}else{
 //save to DB or what you want
}

Answer (score 0):

Provide `id` attribute to form tag like-  `<form action=" " method="POST" id="form_id">` , and while calling you modal you could use-

```
if($("#form-id").valid())
{
   //call your modal
   //if you are using latest version of js, you could this syntax
   $("#Modal_update").modal('show');   
}
```

Make sure you add `jquery.validate.js` in your code.

Comment: I'll try using this code, but i have 2 submit button in 1 form

Comment: Don't use submit button, use  `<button type="button">` tag for both the buttons, and submit the form using ajax.

Comment: i'm not familiar with ajax